# Not moving to Settings in iPod Touch

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiapplication

I have a button . When I click on it I have used this code to go to **settings** in the iPod Touch . But it is not going . iPod touch iOS is 6.1 . Please tell me the problem. Thanks in advance . For reference I have attached the settings screen [image]

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till now Apple not providing the URL Schema for achieving this one in newer versons. upto ios5.0 it was working after that this one depreciated.

Comment: Are you sure sunny? Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: not 100% sure but i too googled about this one in all the ways but for newer versions this one not possible till now.